# How to automatically resize a JTree object?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm trying to get a JTree object to dynamically resize when a node is expanded. By default, the object area is constant and when expanded, the bottom section of the tree gets out of view, unless the window is resized as well. How do I fix this?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`setVisibleRowCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29) method of `JTree` is particularly helpful in conjunction with the `JScrollPane` suggested by @Andrew Thompson.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson's answer proceeded my own small addition; I'd be pleased if you elected to accept his answer, but I defer to you. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 4):

Put the `JTree` in a `JScrollPane`.

---

E.G. (incorporating trashgod's sage tip)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class BasicTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JTree tree = new JTree();
            tree.setVisibleRowCount(10);

            int rows = tree.getRowCount();
            for (int row=rows-1; row>-1; row--) {
                tree.expandRow(row);
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,
                    new JScrollPane(tree));
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Tree in scrollpane]

Comment: simple is best, BTW thanks for link to your web, interesting reading +1

Comment: @trashgod:  It's not what you put *in,* it's what you take *out!*  ;)